# Camera Activity not found?

Tags: android, camera

I've released an app and in the logs, I'm getting this message several times

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN pkg=com.android.camera }
```

I'm calling the camera like this

```
final Intent mainCameraIntent = new Intent();
mainCameraIntent.setPackage("com.android.camera");
mainCameraIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
startActivity(mainCameraIntent);
```

Why am  getting this message? On my device (2.3.3), it works fine. I had issues with 2.1 devices before and also with proguard removing blocks of code, but I'm not sure if this is related to any of those

Answer (score 2):

> Why am getting this message?

Because you should not be using this `Intent`. Not all devices will have `com.android.camera`.

Comment: can you please suggest an alternative way to launch the device camera app?

Comment: @bizso09: You take a picture using `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`: http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/

Comment: I would just like to launch the camera app, and let the user take as many pictures as he wants to. I don't want to process the result. Is that still possible?

Comment: @bizso09: There is no generic `Intent` for that, any more than there is a generic `Intent` to open a calculator.