# Not able to get camera running status

Tags: android, camera

To check whether camera is running or not i am writing these code

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String packageName = actvityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
    if(packageName.equals("android.hardware.camera")||packageName.equals("com.android.camera")){
        Camera_status = "STATUS_ON";
        System.out.println("===on===");
    }else{
        Camera_status = "STATUS_OFF";
        System.out.println("====off====");
    }
```

By using this, i am able to get correct result in android emulator but while testing In real device i an not able to get the correct result.As per the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885367/camera-activity-not-found) by CommonsWare,i think he is correct.So friends may i know how to get the camera on/off status programmatically.

Comment: did you try to see what processes you have and which one could actually be the camera?

Comment: yes...in LogCat i get 09-25 18:09:15.514: I/ActivityManager(61): Displayed com.android.camera/.Camera: +873ms

Comment: i mean, like, in the procInfos list. Apparently, it is not there, so can you post the content of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This its working!!!

```
Camera _camera;
    boolean qOpened = false;
    try {
        _camera=Camera.open();
        qOpened=(_camera!=null);
        if(qOpened){
            Camera_status = "STATUS_OFF";
        }else{
            System.out.println("==nothing to do====");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Camera_status = "STATUS_ON";
        System.out.println("=====Camera running=====");
    }
```